# how to use a custom uitableviewcell for storyboards in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

I am using storyboards to create a custom cell.  I have connected this cell to my tableview in storyboards:

```
import UIKit

class NewsCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var summaryLabel: UILabel!



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

My cellforrowatindexpath and init functions looks like these:

```
var newsItems:[NewsItem]

required init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder){
    newsItems = [NewsItem]()

    let item1 = NewsItem()
    item1.title = "I am so awesome"
    item1.summary = "My awesome summary."

    newsItems.append(item1)

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "NewsCell"
        var cell: NewsCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? NewsCell

        if cell == nil {
            cell = NewsCell()
        }

        let item = newsItems[indexPath.row]

        if let titleLabel = cell.titleLabel{
            titleLabel.text = item.title
        }

        return cell
    }
```

When I do this, my cell shows blank in my tableview.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you connected `titleLabel` with the equivalent label in Interface Builder?

Comment: I went to the split assistant view with storyboard and cell view showing.  I dragged from my label to the cell creating the connection.

Comment: By blank you mean it has no rows? Did you do reloadData on the table view?

Comment: Have you set your prototype cell's class (in your storyboard) to `NewsCell`?

Comment: Have you implemented numberOfRowsInSection:, and returned a non-zero number from it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before we work on your array, let's get the basic cell working:

```
class NewsCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var summaryLabel: UILabel!

}
```

in your Table class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "NewsCell", bundle: nil)!,
            forCellReuseIdentifier: "NewsCell")

    let title = "I am so awesome"
    let summary = "My awesome summary."

    }


func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as NewsCell


cell.titleLabel = title
cell.SummaryLabel = summary

return cell
}
```

Then we can help you with your array if strings.

You can forget the register nib code if in the storyboard.  But it is worth learning how to do.

Comment: You shouldn't be registering a nib for a cell made in the storyboard.

Comment: sorry, I am indeed recommending a Xib file here.